# EXCEL how to use "IF" excel function for adding a digit before a number

Tags: excel

I have a problem with programming as i have a lot of phone numbers from different businesses and i would like to add a "0" in front of all the mobile phone numbers beginning with 7, thus taking off the businesses that does not have their number start with 7, as it is mandatory to have "07" for a mobile phone number. Is there a way i can modify this by using the "IF" function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like:

```
=IF(LEFT(B2,1)="7","0"&B2,B2)
```

this adds a zero at the front of the number when the first character is '7'. let me know how you get on...

Comment: You can even save a bit of space by saying: =IF(LEFT(B2)="7","0","")&B2 [because the presumption of LEFT(B2) is that you only want 1 character unless you specify otherwise.